# Cryptocurrency from Scratch?

Tags: development, currencies

I remember seeing a question a while back about how to code your own cryptocurrency here:
[How to fork Bitcoin and build own cryptocurrency](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/19287/how-to-fork-bitcoin-and-build-own-cryptocurrency)

Unfortunately, it seems to suffer from a lack of in-depth information of how
to "start" the currency in the network. I was wondering what it would take to
implement a new Proof-of-Work/Proof-of-Stake and how to actually get the entire
currency "started".

Comment: You don't "start in" a network -- you're building one of those, too. So realistically, the answer here is "social networking."

Comment: I was looking for something more on the lines of code ;-) but thanks for the answer.

Comment: To create a new Proof-of-Work/Proof-of-Stake system you are going to need to be really creative and possibly know mathematics in depth. May I suggest you read up on how Bitcoin does certain things on the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: primordial, I have experience with creating Proof of work / Proof of stake Crypto Systems, if you have any questions feel free to drop me an email.