# Where do i start for creating altcoin?

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development

Where do i start for creating a bitcoin altcoin? Like for changing block times, names, coin max, etc? I know what i want to change but I don't know where to change the code for the basic things mentioned above.

Comment: You should break this question up into its particular parts.  Here's a general primer with max coins http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/19288/5107  Block times has been answered elsewhere.  The variable is called `nSpacing` or something to that effect.  You'll have to be more specific on "names".

Comment: There are hundreds of altcoins. Your altcoins has a 99% chance of failing and if you can't code and can't capitalise your "I"s properly then there is nothing you can add of value to the altcoin economy.

Comment: For the love of God don't bother bringing a clone coin with no innovation. You won't get rich. You're not doing anyone any favours. You missed the boat. The lowest standard for a new coin now assumes some innovation. Once more please don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

This [post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0) on bitcointalk is a good starting point.

The basic idea is to:

1. fork an existing coin
2. Customize some values (block reward, block time, hash algorithm, etc.)
3. Boot strap the coin by mining then encoding some checkpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not necessarily too technical and depending on your goal, you may want to look for a service that can run your altcoin for you and provide higher level APIs with it. For example: http://www.blockcypher.com.